# How to traverse all values of LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>?

Tags: java, json, collections, treemap

So, I have JSON file and all data I put to `LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>`. If one of JSON field is complex:

```
{
    "val1": "1",
    "val2": "2",
    "val3": {
        "embVal1": "emb1",
        "embVal2": emb2
    },
    "val4": "4"
}
```

like `val3`, map value with `Object` type will transform to other `LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>`, and my structure will look like `LinkedTreeMap<String, LinkedTreeMap<Sting, Object>>`.

If val3 in it body has other complex object, my value of `Object` type will also transform to new `LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>` and so on into the depths of Json tree.

How can I traverse all embedded nodes in structure like this?

Comment: What did you try so far? How do you traverse flat objects?

Comment: @Thomas, I must write some Json comparator, that can show detail defferences between actual and expected jsons

Comment: @Thomas, I think some recursively, but I had never work with structures like this

Answer (score 1):

I did the code below, I didn't think in performance so much but it works well

AppTest.java

```
public class AppTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> node = new LinkedTreeMap<>();
        LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> node2 = new LinkedTreeMap<>();
        LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> node3 = new LinkedTreeMap<>();
        
        node2.put("embembVal1", "embemb1");
        node2.put("embembVal2", "embemb2");
        
        node3.put("embVal1", "emb1");
        node3.put("embVal2", node2);
        
        node.put("val1", "1");
        node.put("val2", "2");
        node.put("val3", node3);
        node.put("val4", "4");
        
        MyJson json = new MyJson();
        json.read(node);
        
        System.out.println(MyJsonBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

MyJson.java

```
public class MyJson {
    
    public void read(LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> node) {
        MyJsonBuilder.append("{");
        
        for(Entry<String, Object> set : node.entrySet()) {
            if(!getInstanceType(set.getValue())) {
                jsonFormat(set.getKey(), set.getValue());
            } else {
                new MyJson().read( (LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) set.getValue() );
            }
        }
        
        MyJsonBuilder.append("}");
    }
    
    private void jsonFormat(String k, Object v) {
        MyJsonBuilder.append( String.format("\"%s\":\"%s\"", k, v) );
    }
    
    private boolean getInstanceType(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof LinkedTreeMap) return true;
        else return false;
    }
   
}
```

MyJsonBuilder.java

```
public class MyJsonBuilder {
    
    private static StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    
    public static void append(String node) {
        jsonBuilder.append(node);
    }
    
    private static String format(String json) {
        String adjustedjson = json;
        if (adjustedjson.contains("\"\"")) adjustedjson = adjustedjson.replaceAll("\"\"", "\",\"");
        if (adjustedjson.contains("}\"")) adjustedjson = adjustedjson.replaceAll("}\"", "},\"");
        
        return adjustedjson;
    }
    
    public static String build() {
        return format(jsonBuilder.toString());
    }
    
}
```